# Как сделать select обязательным, не считая пункта выбранного по умолчанию?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Т.е. я добавляю к required, но он я так понял учитывает и пункт выбранный по умолчанию и тогда смысл теряется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понял.

Надо к `<option>` по умолчанию и не учитывающийся добавить `value=''`

Comment: Отметьте как решение

Comment: через 2 дня только смогу)

Answer (score 0):

В самом `<select>` добавляете опцию required, ничего сложного:

```
<select class='select' required>
    <option selected=''>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: В вопросе сказано, что он и так добавлен